# How do I add elements in python list?

Tags: python

```
weight = [10, 3, 7, 9, 6, 5, 2]

def listsum(numlist):
    sum = 0
    for i in numlist:
        sum = sum + i
    return sum

listsum(weight)
```

I have this simple function to add the values of weight together and am expecting a total of 42 however when I run the function, I don't get any errors or anything.

I am not sure what's going on and have been trying to search various answers for the past 20 mins to no avail. Can someone point me in the right direction here? Thank you

Comment: Works fine for me...`print(listsum(weight))`

Comment: are you indicating that there is no output?

Comment: *Do not shadow built-ins.* Use `S` or `my_sum` instead of `sum`.

Comment: just an fyi you  can also do `def listsum(numlist):
    return sum(numlist)`

Comment: How are you attempting to run this code?  if this is from an interactive window, did you remember to hit "ENTER" after your last line?  If you're running from the command line, there's no output because you didn't print anything.

Answer (score 2):

Just an fyi, you can use the built-in `sum()` function to do the same thing, or if you want a function with the built-in, you can do

```
def listsum(list):
    return sum(list)
```

Your function works perfectly; you just need to wrap the function call in a `print()` statement so you can see the output:

`print(listsum(weight))`

Answer (score 1):

Probably don't need to make a new function to do this, but is working fine for me.

```
>>> weight = [10, 3, 7, 9, 6, 5, 2]
>>> def listsum(numlist):
...     sum = 0
...     for i in numlist:
...         sum = sum + i
...     return sum
... 
>>> listsum(weight)
42
```

Comment: Please, don't use images to give examples. Use `formated text`

Answer (score 1):

I didn't print(listsum(weight)) so the value wasn't showng...